# How do I edit the "switch windows" shortcut from cmd+` to another key instead of `?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an Macbook and I'd like to adjust this shortcut. The ` key is very close to the cmd key, and frequent use is contributing to RSI-type injuries in my left wrist.

If I can change the keyboard shortcut to something like cmd+§, I am hoping the wider span between the keys will help ease/ reduce pain.

I've tried setting this up in System Prefs but I'm not sure what the exact title of the shortcut should be in order to activate it.

Answer (score 1):

The cmd + ' keyboard shortcut can be found under Keyboard Shortcuts -> Keyboard & Text Input. It is called "Move focus to next window in application".